# Custom viewcell with bindable custom object

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms, model-binding

I'm here with a question that is bothering me for the last couple of days and I was unable to find a clear explanation for. What I want to accomplish:
Create a custom ViewCell of which BindableProperty is a complex object.
A this moment I receive a null value in my BindableProperty.
Any tip is of great help.

Here is my ViewCell's Code-Behind:.

```
public partial class ValidatableText : ViewCell
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty BindedObjectProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(
            nameof(ObjectToValidate),
            typeof(ValidatableObject<string>),
            typeof(ValidatableText),
            default(ValidatableObject<string>));


    public ValidatableObject<string> ObjectToValidate
    {
        get
        {
            var value = GetValue(BindedObjectProperty);
            var result = value as ValidatableObject<string>;
            return result;
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(BindedObjectProperty, value);
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ObjectToValidate));
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(propertyName) && propertyName == BindedObjectProperty.PropertyName)
        {
            base.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        }
    }

    public ICommand ValidateInput
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command(() =>
            {
                this.ObjectToValidate.Validate();
            });
        }
    }

    public ValidatableText()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = this;
    }
}
```

The way call this:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <TableView Intent="Form" HasUnevenRows="True">
        <TableRoot >
            <TableSection Title="Creditentials">
                <cells:ValidatableText  ObjectToValidate="{Binding Email}">
                </cells:ValidatableText>
            </TableSection>
        </TableRoot>
    </TableView>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Caller's ViewModel:

```
    public ValidatableObject<string> Email
    {
        get => _email;
        set
        {
            _email = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }        

     public RegisterUserViewModel()
     {
        this.Email = new ValidatableObject<string>();

        this.Email.Validations.Add(new EmailRule<string>(){ValidationMessage = "Invalid email format"});
     }
```

Best regards.

Comment: It could be obvious, but did you set the binding context of your page with your caller ViewModel?

Comment: Yes, was the first thing I checked.

Comment: So put a breakpoint at ObjectToValidate set method.Check if the `value` is being feed, maybe the problem is about conversions. And I think you don't need  the `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ObjectToValidate));` on it, the BindablePropertyClass already handle it.

Comment: One interesting thing that I just noticed is that the ObjectToValidate Set method is never called, nor is the OnObjectToValidatePropertyChanged, method, can you please expand on the "conversion" problem please?

Comment: I was talking about a possible `object` to `ValidatableObject<string>` conversion. But if the set method isn't called, it wouldn't be the case.

Comment: I thought another thing: I don't know about the `TableView`, but the `ListView` have a bind behavior unusual. It has a BindingContext (usually inherited from page) and set explicitly another context to it's children: each item of `ItemsSource` is itself the BindingContext of the corresponding ViewCell item. Can it be the case to Table? Try set the BindingContext of the Section explicitly to your viewModel and see what happens